# Configuring Tipsy with title tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tipsy

I've tried implementing the Tipsy jQuery plugin on my website which is mean't to show title tags as pretty tooltips. But it doesn't appear to be working on my site, can anybody help?

I'd like a tooltip to be shown when I hover over the video thumbnails in the videos pod at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the following line to init your tooltip:

```
$('.tipsy').tipsy();
```

But as you can see the following `img` link does't have a class called `tipsy`.

```
<a class="videobox various iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/I7_iD31Yhjg?autoplay=1&hd=1">
    <img width="74" height="56" title="Fear of Mobs Episode 155 - Murdering Ze Puppeh Doggies" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/I7_iD31Yhjg/1.jpg">
</a>
```

**Update**: Try to fix `$('.tipsy').tipsy();` to `$('a.videobox img').tipsy();`

If you want to change where it gets the tooltip text you can use something like the following.

```
$('.tipsy').tipsy({
    title: 'alt' // it'll get the alt attr, you can use an attr or a callback
});
```

Comment: This kind of worked, it now displays an empty tooltip. How can I get the text that usually appears when hovering over (the title tags) in the tipsy tooltips instead?

Comment: By default it gets the `title` of your element you can change it to an attribute or a callback using the code which I'll put on my update.

Comment: The title element is what I want though but it's showing as blank, I'd like the title of the thumbnail image to show as a the tooltip instead.

Comment: @user1510201 That's the issue, you are getting the `a` title, not the `img` title.